# Discord.py bot - How to make a bot respond depending on the command content?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I make a Discord bot and I want to create a feature when bot reacts depending on the command content

> For example:

```
    if message.content.startswith("!send <:grin:>"):
        await message.channel.send("")
```

```
if message.content.startswith("!send <:angry:>"):
    await message.channel.send("")
```

Making command for every emoji is useless (There are over 3600+ emojis). Any ideas?

Comment: await message.channel.send(message.content.split('<')[1].split('>')[0])
or with re: re.search('\<(.+)>', message.content).group(1)

Comment: Discord.py is unmaintained, use Hikari instead. Code is pretty much the same.
https://github.com/hikari-py/hikari

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to either:

**a- Use a dictionary for each emoji you want to add**

```
emojiDict = {":grin:":,":angry:":}
if message.content.startswith("!send <"):
    emoji = message.content[-7:-1]
    await message.channel.send(emojiDict[emoji])
```

**b- Post whatever the user does after the !send**

```
if message.content.startswith("!send <"):
    emoji = message.content[-7:-1]
    await message.channel.send(emoji)
```

The advantage of method 2 is that you don't need to hardcode each and every emoji, but then the user can also post anything after !send and it will send, even if it is not an emoji.

You can add additional checks to make sure its an emoji (make sure it starts and ends with a ":" as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the commands arguments, like this:

```
@Bot.command()
async def send(ctx, emoji_name):
    await ctx.send(f":{emoji_name}:")
```